# Как заменить позицию в ArrayList objects?

Tags: java, android, массивы

Есть `ArrayList` с кастомным классом:

```
static ArrayList<FoodDiaryClass> foodDiaryList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Я знаю как добавить позицию к массиву:

```
FoodDiary.foodDiaryList.add(new FoodDiaryClass(
                        dateNote, breakfast, dinner, supper, snack, health
                ));
```

Но мне нужно заменить определенную позицию в массиве на новые данные по каждому из полей. У меня есть номер заменяемой позиции:

```
int notePosition;
```

Я так понимаю, нужно использовать конструкцию типа:

```
FoodDiary.foodDiaryList.set (position, Object)
```

Но я не пойму, как именно ее задействовать. Пробую:

```
FoodDiary.foodDiaryList.set(notePosition (
 breakfast, dinner, supper, snack, health, health
)
```

но получаю ошибку

**Как мне заменить строку массива** `notePosition` на новые данные по полям dateNote, breakfast, dinner, supper, snack, health?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Правильная конструкция:

```
FoodDiary.foodDiaryList.set(notePosition, new FoodDiaryClass(
                        dateNote, breakfast, dinner, supper, snack, health
                ));
```

Comment: Если ваш кастоиный класс изменяемый, не проще ли получить объект по индексу и менять его (сеттерами, например)?